Dynamic parameters in Anylogic
hope you're all well.
I'm new here.
I'm having some trouble working with dynamic parameters in Anylogic while developing a discrete simulation.
In resume: I want a delay to be dynamic and follow a triangular distribution, since it's the distribution that adjusts better for the delay time of the employees.
After researching and trying, I've been able to make the program work, but I'm not sure if it's ok.
Imagen 1: here is where I have set the parameter to be dynamic. Default value is a triangular distribution
Imagen 2: this is de delay I want it to be related to the parameter "tiempoAtFarm". I put the "()" sentence so that it calls the function. My doubt is; Why when I click on the delay, the parameter does not highlight in purple? as it happens with static parameters
When I run the program, it runs well with no errors, but I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing.
Thank you so much.

pls only use the anylogic tag to avoid confusing others

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You are doing it ok. In fact, you can skip the dynamic parameter and just type the code directly into the delay duration.
Usually, we use functions: type the code into a function that returns a double, and call the function from the delay block.
PS: You can test stuff like that via traceln(...) commands

Hello Benjamin, nice to meet you! Thank you so much for your answer.
So, it should throw the same results if I do it with a function, or if I do it the way I posted it here, right?
As you can see in the image, when I click on the dynamic parameter, I see a table "Arguments", with the columns "Name" and "Type". Is it ok if I leave it blank? Because I'm not sure what that is for.
I appreciate your help.
Ivan

pls always open new issues for new questions, SOF does not work like a forum but is a Q&A place, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community

oh, and pls upvote if an answer was helpful, helps future users with similar issues
